# Can I subtract guest fees collected from a membership fee when a user registers

Tags: civimember, contributions, cividiscount

Our club allows people to come out as guests, for which we collects guest fee. If that person later chooses to become a member, we deduct that guest fee from their membership fee.

I know I can create different fee structures, but that assumes the person entering the information, whether that's a club executive or the member selects the correct thing. I haven't found a mechanism for membership upgrades, or a means of replacing one membership with another but applying a credit against the new one.

Is there a way with CiviCRM to automate this process?

Comment: Part of the answer, I believe, lies with the renewal engine.

Since our club uses a fixed-term membership, someone who has registered as a guest can renew their membership and select a different membership type. Now the question is, how do I subtract the contribution paid in the first membership from the fee paid for the up-sell or new membership?

Comment: I configured a guest membership type, and registered a user as a guest, then tried using the renew process to change their membership type to member, but in the process it extended their membership by a year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is when they come out as a guest and pay the fee, you provide them with an automatic discount from the CiviDiscount extension, which is applicable to the full "Member" membership type and is automatically given to folks with a current "Guest" membership.

[image: Auto discount membership]

You may need to play with settings to see for sure if it will work in your case.

- Extension page: [CiviDiscount](https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount)
- Github: [org.civicrm.module.cividiscount](https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount)

> **CiviDiscount**: This extension allows the admin to create and manage
>   discount codes that can be used on membership and event pages.
>
> **Features**:
>
> - Support for price sets and individual items in a price set
> - Use of monetary or percentage based discounts
> - Automatic discount based on membership
> - Generate random discount codes
> - Usage and assigned code tabs on a contact record
> - Code summary screen displays usage for a given discount code
> - Option to apply discounts to additional participants

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Do you know if it's possible to automatically generate the discount code and e-mail it when they register, or would that have to be manual?

Comment: I think you can set an automatic discount for Guest members that are current. (no code needed)